# Does the Empiricist Aspect of Kantian Idealism Refute Mellasioux's Anti-Correlationist Argument in "After Finitude"?

Tags: metaphysics

In After Finitude by Quentin Mellasioux, QM argues that the existence of the Arche-fossil creates a conflict between the intersubjective objectivism of the current scientific paradigm and the correlationist idealism, which states that an object cannot be known in-itself independently of the filter of the Subject.

However, can't an Idealist safely counter this anti-correlationism with the argument that the intersubjective objective scientific paradigm is limited by the idealist conception and thereby are not in fact accessing the arche-fossil in-itself, thereby not having a conflict in the first place?

I need someone to explain to me how this does not immediately refute QM's argument.

Comment: Maybe you can try to explain what *Arche-fossil* is according to QM...

Comment: If they are simply fossil remain of ancient civilizations, what is the difference with other historical evidences? According to the "intersubjective objectivism of the current scientific paradigm" they are physical evidences of *historical facts* that can provide us with indirect knowledge of ancient times.

Comment: If according to "idealism, we cannot know an object independently of the filter of the Subject" our knowledge of ancient times through fossils has the same status of our knowledge of Napoleon through historical records.

Comment: Maybe useful FA Muller, [The Paradox of the Arche-fossil: An Analysis of Meillassoux’s Challenge to Correlationism, Idealism included (2022)](https://dialectica.philosophie.ch/dialectica/article/view/21/21)

Comment: This is not a satisfactory answer. It is clear that you do not know what the arche-fossil is, as defined by QM. In QM's definition, the Arche-fossil is that which predates human existence and therefore any existence of the su ject to observe the thing as it presents itself to us (the phenomena). QM seems to use this argument in order to posit that the rationalist portion of Kantian Idealism is incoherent with the current scientific process and knowledge, as we can clearly describe the events of the formation of Earth before any observers. However it is unclear as to the status of the empirical

Comment: Perfect; but IF we assume that there is something that predates "human existence and therefore any existence of the subject to observe the thing" this is simply the standard assumption of scientific knowledge. Is this a refutation of Kantism? Obviously, Kant would disagree: scientific knowledge was already developed at Kant's time and Kant was aware of it.

Comment: But the basic insight of Kant (in a nutshell) is **not** that there is no reality without subject, but that there is no knowledge without subject... and this is quite harmless. The conundrum (that Kant aimed to solve) is: how objective knowledge is possible if there is no way to left aside the subject?

Comment: I believe I am in agreement with you as of this moment in time. To me, QM seems to claim that a contradiction arises since the prediction of the existence of something in such a past that no humans were or could be available to experience it, leads to a situation where correlationism posits that such a thing cannot exist since you cannot have access to the thing in-itself or have been there to experience the thing as presented to the subject. What I am trying to understand ultimately is what QM's response is to those who say that the interpretation of such a arche-fossil is from the context of

Comment: the present is. As to how he responds to the "retrojection" as he calls it, of a current interpretation within the context of correlationism of a past event. I want to know what his argument is, as I think this makes or breaks his whole thesis.

Comment: Indeed Mellasioux's arche-fossil argument is a central evidence for his *ancestrality* thesis against the Kantian central thesis which is *to be is to be a correlate*. In other words a truth is the *bearer* of theoretical movements that form among *themselves* as things-in-themselves a historicity both profound and discontinuous and thus truth is always necessarily *post-evental* while ironically the events themselves are necessarily super-chaotically contingent endangering PSR. QM needs to defend his thesis in the observer participatory principle of all the observables in quantum mechanics...

Comment: So are you saying you defend his idea? That there is a disconnect between the actual order of events in the universe and the perception of events by the Subject. And furthermore this alludes to that either the Subject is able to grasp the object in-itself (no correlate), or there is no way to support the arche-fossil as legitimate knowledge, which poses a conflict between science and "correlationism", which needs to be resolved. And you mention quantum mechanics because of the measurement problem?

Comment: I doubt the conflict between science and correlationism has to be resolved as our scientific knowledge about the big bang or arche-fossil no matter how correct deemed, is correlate and theory, which is different from the assumed event-in-itself. I wonder why the forged term "correlationism" is needed since the usual term since ancient is called representationalism and it's not clear in the limited translated English literature what's the difference btw his "speculative realism" and the standard disjunctive naive realism. Quantum mech suggests on the bit level no probe no observable reality...

Comment: This is a 95% satisfactory answer. You lost 5% on the last sentence but the rest of what you just said was exactly what I was looking for. I suppose what separates "speculative realism" is the added attack on the original conception of Transcendental Idealism, which still has a defense in the form of the phenomena defined as the *manifestation* of the arche-fossil in which is described in terms of the categories which are interpreted through the correlate, but it seems other than this QM returns to posit a relatively unoriginal naive realist thesis with strong rationalist elements. Objections?

Comment: No objections at all as indeed influenced by his mentor Badiou who holds set-theoretic math ontology realism of multiplicities, QM has strong rationalism component is his philosophy, and we yet to see his entire thesis. Btw, the last sentence about quantum mech's famous observer-participatory principle of informational reality was expounded by John Wheeler in his famous essay *It from bit*...